# Spring Boot TestRestTemplate return null body

Tags: spring-boot

Havin a quite very simple test class followed by a video tut:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestClassTest {

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate testRestTemmplate;

@Test
public void test_one() {

    String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/v1/read";
    UriComponents builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).build();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("accept", "application/json");

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemmplate.exchange(builder.toString(), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println(response.getBody());

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());

}
```

}

The underlying controller class for test looks like:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/read", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> data() {

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).header("status", "completed").body("fertig!");

}
```

}

Some issues i wondering with:

- Running the test will evaluate to green thats fine but if i change the url in the test it will be also OK
- The body from response is null and
- the header i set within the ResponseEntity is no part of the response from testResttemplate.

Where are my misunderstandings?

Edit: here are my imports:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
```

As seen this are only the "standard" import coming from spring dependencies. Nothing exotics.

Comment: this seems to be perfectly working for me. I think you might add some wrong import packages. Check your imports and try again. it should work fine.

Comment: Oh man, I can not make a replica via the same codes as yours. They work completely well.   Have you tried to reload the output directory via  ```mvn clean``` or something?

Comment: Thanks guys for the hints you gave me. I don't know where the problem was. I rebuild the project completely and now it works!